# Since the gcd$(a,b) = p$, where $p$ is prime, calculate the $\gcd(a^3,b)$ and the $\gcd(a^2,b^3)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

My attempt

$p\mid a$ and $p\mid b,$ then

$a = pq_1$ ,  $b = pq_2$

$\gcd(a^2,b)$

$a^2 = (p^2 * q_1^2)$ ,$\ b = p*q_2$

To find the $\gcd(a^2,b)$, I have to do the euclidean algorithm:

$(p^2q_1^2)\bmod (pq_2)$

From there I can't Go on...

Answer (score 5):

You know that $p$ divides both $a$ and $b$, but no other prime does, and $p^2$ doesn't divide both.  So $\gcd(a^3, b)$ could be either $p$,  $p^2$ or $p^3$, and
$\gcd(a^2,b^3)$ could be either $p^2$ or $p^3$.

Comment: Just a little addendum: For $\gcd(a^3,b),$ taking $a=b=p$ gives $p$, taking $a=p,b=p^2$ gives $p^2$ and $a=p,b=p^3$ gives $p^3$. For $\gcd(a^2,b^3)$, $a=b=p$ gives $p^2$ and $a=p^2,b=p$ gives $p^3$, so all of the values listed are indeed attainable

Comment: @Robert Israel, I need to prove by manipulation, and I can't only say what it could be.